# MySQL JOIN two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I'm sorry about the ambiguous title - I couldn't come up with an explanation for the behaviour I want without giving examples. Also, if this is a duplicate thread, please point me to the correct one and I'll delete it. I couldn't search for what I wanted because, as I said above, it's hard to explain...

Anyway, I want to select data from two tables. One holds a bunch of projects, whereas another holds multiple checklist items for each project. I have a very primitive `LEFT JOIN` query at the moment, which returns this (there is only one project, at the moment):

```
name                    description
Project file symlinks   One
Project file symlinks   Two
Project file symlinks   seven
Project file symlinks   ahahahahaha
Project file symlinks   many
Project file symlinks   ANOTHER ONE
```

What I'd *like* to happen is this, for each project in the projects table:

```
name                    description
Project file symlinks   One
                        Two
                        seven
                        ahahahahaha
                        many
                        ANOTHER ONE
```

Or null, it doesn't matter. Essentially, I want to only print the project name once, but print all it's corresponding checklist items.

Here is the query I currently have:

```
SELECT Projects.name, DevProgress.description
FROM DevProgress
LEFT JOIN Projects
ON Projects.id = DevProgress.projectID
```

Can anyone offer a MySQL `JOIN` query so that I can get the behaviour I want? Thanks for any help,

**EDIT**

Thanks very much to dcp for helping me out. I eventually came up with this `LEFT JOIN` query, posted as reference:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(description) AS checklist 
FROM Projects LEFT JOIN DevProgress ON Projects.id = DevProgress.projectID 
GROUP BY name;
```

And the output:

```
name                      checklist
Project file symlinks     One,Two,seven,ahahahahaha,many,ANOTHER ONE
Testing Project numer 1   NULL
```

James

Comment: can your post your current query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_concat` to get all the descriptions together for each project:

```
SELECT name,GROUP_CONCAT(description) FROM project GROUP BY name;
```

So this will print the distinct project name, along with all the descriptions of that project on a single row, and each description will be comma delimited.

Sample:

```
create table project (name varchar(100), description varchar(100));

insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'One');
insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'Two');
insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'seven');
insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'ahahahahaha');
insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'many');
insert into project values ('Project file symlinks', 'ANOTHER ONE');

SELECT name,GROUP_CONCAT(description) FROM project GROUP BY name;
```

Results:

```
name                       GROUP_CONCAT(description)
'Project file symlinks'    'One,Two,seven,ahahahahaha,many,ANOTHER ONE'
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you post some example output?

Comment: @JamWaffes - I posted a sample script along with the output.

Comment: Thanks! I can get PHP to do the string splitting. I was mainly looking for a way to do one query instead of like, 20, for each page load.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know very much about mySQL, but it's doable in SQL Server, so it might be possible in mySQL also.

But my point is that even though it might be doable it would be pretty ugly, because SQL just isn't designed this way. In SQL each record of the result set is independent from the other ones. This has several advantages - for example you can apply an additional filter to the result set (if you decide you want only descriptions starting with "ahahaha"), you can reorder it (if you want to sort by description), you can internally parallelize the query and so on without losing information.

This is why some things in SQL are just a bit harder than in other languages, for example numbering your output, querying hierarchies, transposing the output or give special treatment to the first of a group of items.

So your best options might be to either live with the output and post-process it the way you want (which should be pretty trivial - just keep a variable with the last project name and replace the name with empty string if its the same as that last one) or use dcp's answer and flatten the group to a single result row.